# Assigning the time stamp when a ODE system solver becomes stiff to a variable

Tags: differential-equations

How does one go ahead to assign the time stamp whereby a system becomes stiff to a variable? I'm interested in doing a root search on the domain spanning from
t = 0 to t_f = time_stiff - ε.

In order for my code to run smoothly and not have to put in the t_f by hand, how might I have the machine output the t_f so that I might assign it to a variable that the code may continue to use.

I ask because I'm looking to run this programs thousands of times iteratively and would like to have it run overnight without any assistance.

[image: System becomes stiff indicator]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, since the integration stops precisely at the value where the stiffness detector fires, we can use the undocumented capabilities of `InterpolatingFunction[]` to extract that endpoint.

Since you've forgotten to provide an example, I shall use my own. A relatively simple stiff problem is this simplified flame propagation model due to Larry Shampine:

```
With[{δ = 1*^-11}, 
     f = y /. First @ NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^2 - y[x]^3, y[0] == δ},
                              y, {x, 0, 2/δ}]];
```

If you try this out, you will see the message `NDSolve::ndsz` along with the point where it stopped. To get that point, do this:

```
f["Domain"][[1, -1]]
   9.846458146821846*^10
```

You should now be able to use this for further computations.